# How to get values of different columns in based on thir column in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have model `Consignment` . Which  has two addresses `delivery_address` and `pickup_address`.  I need to get these addresses in the form of array. If the conisgnment is pickup it should put pickup_address in array if type is delivery it should put delivery_address in array.

Currently I am doing this

```
 $consignments  = Consignment::select('delivery_address','pickup_address')->whereIn('runsheet_id',$run_sheet_ids)->get();
        $pickup_address = $consignments->pluck('pickup_address')->toArray();
        $delivery_address = $consignments->pluck('delivery_address')->toArray();
```

Problem with this approach is it always give both of addresses .
Is there anyway I can do this in single query because I need to avoid performance issues as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
$condition = "if(type='pickup',pickup_address,delivery_address) as address";
$addresses  = Consignment::selectRaw($condition)
                               ->whereIn('runsheet_id',$run_sheet_ids)
                               ->pluck('address');
```

You can change `type='pickup'` with your condition

Comment: how it is working? I mean if type == pickup what it is doing?

Comment: how do you know if the Consignment is pickup or delivery ? i assume you have a column to identify the type ,right ?